# Display and resize multiple images according to browser width

Tags: html, css, image, responsive-design, responsive

I'd like to be able to display up to 5 images on the same line, depending on the browser width.

Depending on the browser size, I can display more or fewer images, from a single image on mobile to a maximum of 5 on desktop.

The images are resized according to the browser size and are displayed or hidden according to some breakpoints.

[image: Image resizing and displaying]

Does anyone have any ideas on how to do this?

Comment: Responsive sizing with media queries, use Bootstrap or look at their source code for ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There're several way to accomplish what you want but, basically, you'll have to use CSS media queries to do it:

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

#container {
  display: flex;
  gap: 1rem;
}

img { 
  width: 100%;
  display: none;
}

@media (min-width: 200px) {
  #image1 { display: initial; }
}

@media (min-width: 400px) {
  #image2 { display: initial; }
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  #image3 { display: initial; }
}

@media (min-width: 800px) {
  #image4 { display: initial; }
}

@media (min-width: 1000px) {
  #image5 { display: initial; }
}



<div id="container">
  <img id="image1" src="https://picsum.photos/300">
  <img id="image2" src="https://picsum.photos/300">
  <img id="image3" src="https://picsum.photos/300">
  <img id="image4" src="https://picsum.photos/300">
  <img id="image5" src="https://picsum.photos/300">
</div>
```

See it on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/Vi100/pen/xxQXjNo)

Comment: I used your solution but I updated the img width to adapt the height : width: calc(20% - 1rem); where 1rem is the gap value.

https://codepen.io/Nicolas-Dos-Santos/pen/XWyeGya

Answer (score 0):

The quickest way is to utilize a responsive front-end framework like [Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/getting-started/introduction/).
The example below took about 10 minutes to put together. If you just want to borrow from them, you can run the snippet and click "full page" then inspect the elements to see the styles applied.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-9ndCyUaIbzAi2FUVXJi0CjmCapSmO7SnpJef0486qhLnuZ2cdeRhO02iuK6FUUVM" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container py-5">
  <div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="col-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="https://placehold.co/600x400">
    </div>
    <div class="col-6 col-sm-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="https://placehold.co/600x400">
    </div>
    <div class="d-none d-sm-block col-4 col-md-3 col-lg-2">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="https://placehold.co/600x400">
    </div>
    <div class="d-none d-md-block col-3 col-lg-2">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="https://placehold.co/600x400">
    </div>
    <div class="d-none d-lg-block col-2">
      <img class="img-fluid" src="https://placehold.co/600x400">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```